# Why doesn't google sheets show the full array returned by my function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I've been writing a custom function that returns a 365 element array. The problem is that it just doesn't seem to return the values I'd expect. Some of the initial values display, but not others.

The weird thing is that the log files do show the data that I would expect. It's just when I try to output the data to Google sheets that it goes missing.

Which is why I'm wondering if there is some sort of limit on the data that I can return.

**A bit more background**

My google sheet enables staff to record holiday that they have booked. They enter their holiday in the format Name, StartDate, EndDate.

But I'd also like to show the data in something more like a Gantt chart, with days of the year along the top row and members of staff along the left hand column.

So my function loops through each entry in the holiday table until it finds a matching staff name, then it puts an X in the appropriate days. I call the function again for each staff name until I've fully populated the whole array.

```
function myFunction(LeaveDates, StaffName, YearStart) {

  var ResultsArray = new Array(365);
  var MillisecondsInDay = 24*60*60*1000;

  for (var i = 0; i < LeaveDates.length; i++) {
    if (LeaveDates[i][0] == StaffName) {
      for (var j = ((LeaveDates[i][2] - YearStart) / MillisecondsInDay); j < (((LeaveDates[i][3] - YearStart) / MillisecondsInDay)+1); j++) {
       ResultsArray[j] = LeaveDates[i][6];
      }
      Logger.log("Start Date: " + LeaveDates[i][2] + " - End Date: " + LeaveDates[i][3] + " - Type: " +  ResultsArray[j-1]);
    }
  }

  return ResultsArray;
}
```

`LeaveDates` is the range of cells that contains the holiday data

`StaffName` is the name of the current member of staff e.g. John Smith

`YearStart` is the first day of the current year i.e. 01/01/2017

When I call this function from a cell it only populates some of the cells that I'd expect it to. The exact number changes depending on the input data. Sometimes it returns just the first two instances of holiday. Other times it returns the first five. But it's not like it only returns holiday up to a certain date

But the logs show that the data in the array has been populated correctly. So I'm very confused.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong here, but wanted to mention I have written custom functions that return thousands of cells, so I can confirm there is no low limit on the total number of cells you can return

Comment: I think you've reached the point where you need to spend some quality time with your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone who took some time to read my question.

I realised after a good night's sleep that the problem was with my index to the array (`j`). `j` was the number for the day of the year (i.e. a number between 0 and 364)

I calculated it by dividing the date by the number of milliseconds in the day. Which works well until the clocks change for daylight savings (British Summer Time). So any entries after the end of March returned array indices that were not whole numbers.

I added `Math.round()` to my calculation to ensure that I get an integer result and now it works as intended.

I'm a bit surprised that I didn't get any errors when I tried to assign values to non-integer places in the array. Does anyone know of a reason why that is? Are there occasions when you should be able to use non-integer values?